# How to check Truststore expiry date

Tags: ssl-certificate, truststore

How to check truststore validity/expiry date? 
Is there any command through which it can be checked?

Answer (score 0):

One of the method I got is use this command: **openssl x509 -text -in /tmp/truststore**

Example output might have the validity details as below:

```
Validity
            Not Before: May  4 15:06:14 2012 GMT
            Not After : May  4 15:16:14 2019 GMT
```